# Go build 1.7 on "darwin/amd64" checks the "vendor tree" path, but "linux/amd64" does not?

Tags: go, build

I am trying to build the same Go project, but one on a Mac, and the other on a Linux server, using the same command:

```
go build -i myproject.go
```

I am trying to troubleshoot why it cannot find some vendor libraries when building on the Linux server.

Locally, on my Mac, I see that it searches through a path called `vendor tree`:

```
myproject.go:1:1: cannot find package "myproject/myvendorlib" in any of:
    /blabla (vendor tree)
    /blabla (from $GOROOT)
    /blabla (from $GOPATH)
```

Which is good - it's what I expect and want (as the vendor library is actually there).

However, on the Linux server it seems to only search through the `$GOROOT` and the `$GOPATH` directories, not the `vendor tree` directory:

```
myproject.go:1:1: cannot find package "myproject/myvendorlib" in any of:
    /blabla (from $GOROOT)
    /blabla (from $GOPATH)
    /blabla
```

What dictates that it also checks the `vendor tree` directory on the Mac, but on the Linux server, it does not attempt to check in those directories?

Comment: Do you have an old version of Go on the Linux server?

Comment: No, when i do "go version" i see 1.7 Linux/amd64. On my Mac its 1.7 darwin/amd64.

Comment: Did you make any inroads with this? I just set up a Jenkins job with Go 1.7.1 and it behaves the same - no checking in the vendor tree.

Comment: It appears that you need the project to be somewhere under the ```src``` directory in your ```GOPATH```.